# Apollo v3 Graphql concatPagination for a specific field of a query?

Tags: apollo-client, graphql-js

I am fairly newbie when it comes down to graphql. I have the following schema

```
       type query {
        allJobs (
         limit: Int
         cursorId: String
        ): JobSearchResults!

        type JobSearchResults {
         jobs: [Job!]
         hasMoreJobs: Boolean!
        }
       }
```

So there is the query `allJobs` and the result is an object with `jobs` array and a simply boolean `hasMoreJobs` to signal the end of the jobs.

On the client side I am able to query this and get results, but I am totally confused on how to **cache** these results. On ApolloClient I have the following:

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        // cache the previous results and concat the new results to original data
        allJobs: concatPagination(), 
      },
    },
  },
}),
```

I know that this would work if I was just returning an array of `jobs` like that.

```
type query {
     allJobs (
     limit: Int
     cursorId: String
     ): [Jobs]!
```

My question is if there is a way to use `concatPagination` to cache only the `jobs: [Job!]` from the original query.

Or if there is a better way to deal with this problem? Maybe I need to rethink and reconstruct the original schema?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the solution of your problem here:

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/pagination-and-infinite-scrolling-in-apollo-client-59ff064aac61/

Comment: UpdateQuery() is being removed in the next big release of Apollo Client, hence why I think he asked regarding concatPagination() specifically.